# How to fetch new API data periodically

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I'm a beginner level developer and I was practicing using APIs by fetching data from a url that updates its data every 5 seconds. I used setInterval on my fetch function but it keeps logging the same data even when I go to the link directly and see that it's changed.

This is my code using react js:

```
   getData = async () => {
   const fetchData = await fetch("JSON-url");
   const resp = await fetchData.json();
   const timeStampData = await resp.timestamp;
   

   console.log(timeStampData);
 };

 componentDidMount() {
   this.getData();
   this.interval = setInterval(() => this.getData(), 6000);
 }
```

I also tried changing the `const`  to `let` thinking it stopped it from changing but it still didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a caching issue. Try busting the cache by passing in a GET parameter that makes the URL unique, causing the browser to fetch the data instead of relying on cache. Something like this:

```
let uniqueId = new Date().getTime(); // get a unique id - this grabs seconds since unix epoch
const fetchData = await fetch("https://example-json?v=" + uniqueId); // pass variable in as a new parameter. "v" in this case is arbitrary
```

Comment: It works, thanks. It returned JSONP so I had to turn the data to a string then use the replace method to remove padding before converting it back to JSON again but it fixed my original issue.